# Finite generation of stack cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be an Artin stack of finite type. Does it follows that its (say, $\ell$-adic or de Rham) cohomology $\text{H}^*(X)$ is a finitely generated algebra?

For instance, $\text{H}^*(\text{B}\mathbf{G}_m)=k[t]$ has a single generator (of degree two), and similarly for other reductive algebraic groups.

---

Essentially, I think my problem is understanding how taking a colimit (of the nerve of the stack's atlas) interacts with finite generation of cohomology. Indeed, any argument I can think of begins "take a presentation of $X$ by finite type schemes, ... ".

Comment: I think this is already false for $BG_m$.

Comment: Finiteness of individual cohomology groups follows from Theorem 3.1.6 of Behrend’s thesis: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/thesis.pdf It is certainly in other sources, but I learned some of this stuff in Berkeley many years ago.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion The ring $k[t]$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks, though I was aware of this and definitely asking the stronger question about finite generation.

Comment: Perhaps what @Satan'sMinion means is that, if you look at the stack $B\mathbb{G}_m$ over a field $k$ that is not algebraically closed, then the cohomology is quite different from what you wrote (e.g., it has a contribution coming from the $\ell$-adic cohomology of $k$).

Comment: Sorry, I read the question too quickly. Over an alg closed base field I think the answer should be yes, I will try to prove it...